# Buffers not showing on map but viewable in Table of Contents of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I am completing Assignment 9-2 in GIS Tutorial ArcGIS 10.1 Book. I am suppose to set the map to a UTM for California (either 10N or 11N). I am then suppose to add a California Counties layer and Earthquakes layer (which has the same projection as my map and was added from my File Geodatabase). Then I set up a definition query in my Earthquakes layer to have only the earthquakes with an MMI of 7 AND after the year of 1985.

I am suppose to have a 20 mile buffer for each earthquake. I went to Geoprocessing -> Buffer -> Selected my Earthquakes layer -> Saved the output in my File Geodatabase -> Linear Unit as 20 miles -> Dissolve Unit: None. The buffer was added to my Table of Contents, but nothing showed up on my map. I made sure that the buffer had the NAD 1983 projection which was what the map asked for. I also clicked "Zoom to Layer," and only saw small dots with lines coming out of them, but no buffer on my Earthquakes. I also tried to go to export the layer into a UTM projection. However, even with a UTM projection, the buffer layer wouldn't show on the map.

I am not sure why I am getting this error.